# How can I retrieve the common substring between the end of a string and the beginning of another string?

Tags: javascript

Is there any simpler way (ideally from a builtin I missed from the doc) to retrieve the common substring between the end of a string and the beginning of another string? For example abc**def** and **def**ghi should return **def**.

```
abcdef
   defghi
=========
   def
```

My current implem:

```js
const a = "abcdef";
const b = "defghi";

function findCommonEndStart(a, b) {
  let common = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= a.length; i++) {
    const sub = a.slice(-i, a.length);
    if (b.startsWith(sub)) {
      common = sub;
    }
  }
  return common;
}

console.log(findCommonEndStart(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I did it.

```js
let a = "abdef";
let b = "defdklc";

function func(x, y) {
  for (i in x) {
    if (x.substr(-i, x.length) == y.substr(0, i)) {
      console.log(x.substr(-i, x.length))
    }
  }
}

func(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for simple regular expression:

```
let str = 'abcdef defghi';
let find = str => str.match(/(\w+)\b.+\b(?:\1)/m)?.[1];

let result = find(str); // result = 'def'
```